# python-social-auth - failed to login django admin via google authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-authentication, python-social-auth

I made a Django application to implement Google 0auth2 service by using  **[python-social-auth](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io)** package and made as per the official documentation. I successfully made the application and passed the authentication procedure. But, the problem is; after the authentication procedure, the `new-user` is not logged in. The `new-user`, the user created by Google auth is visible on **Django Admin page** under **User** section. Hope someone can solve my issue. I'm adding my code here.

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gq(+ymm#x$*#k)kbz0&6+qpg%o=-q)6_+v!_^&f%q=kgq=*2ks'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',


]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'GauthDemo.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates', ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'GauthDemo.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    # },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'XXXXXXEfsC'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
]


LOGIN_URL = '/auth/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/auth_ok/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse


def authtemp(request):
    print("\n\n HTTP \n\n")
    return render(request, 'auth.html')


def auth_ok(request):
    print("\n\n HTTP Response\n\n")
    return HttpResponse("Auth OK")


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^auth/', authtemp),
    url(r'^auth_ok', auth_ok),

]
```

Comment: Relevant: [Return the user to the original page](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#return-the-user-to-the-original-page)

Comment: Could you try moving the social-django urls to the bottom of the list?